# Open a linux port without using iptables in Centos?

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-kernel, port, iptables

just a quick question, is it possible to open a port on linux Centos without using iptables? If so, how do I do that from the command line?

Comment: define 'open a port'

Comment: And the answer might be no, since iptables are used to block ports.

Comment: What about opening a tunnel- thats how i bypass firewalls at work.. *evil laugh*

Answer (score 0):

If a port is blocked by iptables then it is not possible to open it without modifying iptables config. It would be a security flaw otherwise.